# How to convert time from Asia/Kolkata Timezone to Asia/Tokyo Timezone, then insert the Asia/Tokyo specific date to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, timezone, apache-nifi

My Date is in the format **2020-07-08 00:00:00** Asia/Kolkata

- I want to convert it to **2020-07-08 03:30:00** Asia/Tokyo,
- Then insert this date **2020-07-08 03:30:00** as ISO date to MongoDB.

I tried, with ISODate function, which takes DateFormat and Timezone, but it created the date **5 H 30 M** ahead of this time, which should be **3 H 30 M** ahead.
As Tokyo time is **3 H 30 M** ahead of India time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$dateFromParts` to manipulate `ISODate` to any required format.

Check if the below query helps you out

```
db.test4.aggregate([
     {$project:{
         "original": "$date",
         "convertedDate": {
             '$dateFromParts': {
                 'year': {$year:{date:'$date'}},
                 'month': {$month:{date:'$date'}},
                 'day': {$dayOfMonth:{date:'$date'}},
                 'hour': {$hour:{date:'$date'}},
                 'minute': {$minute:{date:'$date'}},
                 'second': {$second:{date:'$date'}},
                 'millisecond': {$millisecond:{date:'$date'}},
                 'timezone': '-0330',
             }
         }
     }}
 ])
```